# KDE Wallet not working in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: ssh, kubuntu, password, kde, kwallet

Recently upgraded from Kubuntu 17.10 to Kubuntu 18.04.

In 17.10, KDE Wallet was working as expected. It stored all my wi-fi passwords, SSH passwords, etc.

After the upgrade, it started asking me for wi-fi password and SSH password.

Today, when I accessed Settings -> KDE Wallet, there was no sign of any wallet. When I tried creating a new one, I could not. The program became unresponsive.

When I launched KDE Wallet Manager, there was no wallet. I could not create one. The program became unresponsive.

How do I set things right?

Comment: Have you tried to launch it from terminal to check error messages?

Comment: There's no kwallet application!

Comment: if it installed , open terminal and type first letters from app you want , this case kwa and then press TAB  two times , this way is displayed all app that possibly match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem. I made these steps to make it works again (maybe only one was necessary)

- `kill` all processes which I found via `ps aux | grep kwallet`  (there was three and I think one of these processes can "lock" wallet opening. Because when I killed it pop up for password appeared)
- Run update - After upgrade to 18.04 I ran `apt update && apt upgrade` and it found 3 updates (libpam-kwallet-common, libpam-kwallet4, libpam-kwallet5)
- Reboot once again - After login I was asked for password into wallet and it looks kwallet working again.

Hope it helps.

Best regards,
cr4wen